# Has the (Dune universe) Solari ever been represented physically?

Tags: dune, money

I wanted to design a Solari note, but I'm wondering if the Solari has ever been represented physically in any other official Dune-related media.

Comment: I've had a look through the Illustrated Dune, the Dune Encyclopaedia, the Dune RPG modules and the new Dune Imperium games and none of them have a physical depiction of a solari note or coin.

Comment: Interestingly, in the novels there are references to solari coins, but not solari notes.

Comment: May be we shall see them in the upcoming series)

Answer (score 8):

The 'officially licenced' Unicorn Games Collectible Card Game set [Thunder at Twlight - Chapter 3](https://ccgtrader.co.uk/games/dune-ccg/thunder-at-twilight-chapter-3/) contains the card '[*Byzantine Corruption*](https://ccgtrader.co.uk/card/145594/byzantine-corruption)'. Two hands appear to be handling (or counting) golden Solari coins.

[image] [image]